# file forgetting dependent reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with code called 'constants.xlsm', which other .xlsm spreadsheets use as a dependent reference.

I have a new spreadsheet file where I want to use a function from 'constants.xlsm' in a worksheet formula. The function is =ToOptionSymbol(...).

The function works as expected while the new file has a reference to 'constants', but does not want to remember that it has a reference to 'constants' when it is closed and reopened.

The 'new' file has no code modules of it's own. How can I make the 'new' file remember the reference between sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in addition to saving the workbook as `.xlsm`, it also needs to contain a `VbaProject`, to which the `VbReferences` to other files are added.

Try the any of these:

1. Add a new module to the new workbook.
2. If you don't want to have an empty module in the "new file" you can also add a dummy procedure into the `ThisWorkbook` code pane, such as this:

   ```
   Private Sub Dummy_Procedure()
   End Sub
   ```

Any of the above suggestions will force the workbook to create a `VbaProject`, thus keeping the `vbReference` to the `constants.xlsm` `vbProject`.